# Converting textarea to json /with other float values/

Tags: php, json

Hello i have a problem with json format.

Here is code

```
If (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']='submit')
{
$data['value1']=(float)$_POST['val1']; //values from input fields

...
...
...
$data['value6']=(float)$_POST['val6'];
$data['textar']=$_POST ['textarea'];//from textarea
$data['textar2']=$_POST ['textarea2']; //from textarea

json_encode($data,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
}

postR($data);

function postR($data)
{
$curl = curl_init();
$url = COC_HOST."xxx";

echo $url;


curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, //temporary, to ignore ssl cert errors
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 300,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "authorization: ".COC_HEADER_AUTHENTICATION,
        "cache-control: no-cache",
        "content-type: application/json"
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    return false;
} else {

    return $response;

}
```

}

HTML

```
<form method="post" action=""> 

Value1:<input type="text" size="5"  value="" name="val1">
Value2:<input type="text" size="5"  value="" name="val2">
Value3:<input type="text" size="5"  value="" name="val3">
Value4:<input type="text" size="5"  value="" name="val4">
Value5:<input type="text" size="5"  value="" name="val5">
Value6:<input type="text" size="5"  value="" name="val6">

IDs :<input type="textarea" value="" name="textarea">
Notes:<input type="textarea" value="" name="textarea2">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

But this returns me an error that there are strings of course.
Textar and textar2 are textareas while rest data are float. How to convert this textarea to be valid json ? 
Value1 to value6 has to be float as is for money fields.

Code above write from hand,as i dont have access to computer.

I tried insert nulls to textarea values but it doesnt work and this fields wont be empty in future.

Thank you.

Comment: What is your input to the textareas?

Comment: <input type="textarea" value="" name="textarea"> some text

Comment: please include your form in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks okay except for the extra `)`, in `json_encode($data,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));` There's nothing wrong with this code, unless you are doing something else.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="test" method="post" action="">

    Value1:<input type="text" size="5"  value="" name="val1">
    Value2:<input type="text" size="5"  value="" name="val2">
    Value3:<input type="text" size="5"  value="" name="val3">
    Value4:<input type="text" size="5"  value="" name="val4">
    Value5:<input type="text" size="5"  value="" name="val5">
    Value6:<input type="text" size="5"  value="" name="val6">

    IDs :<input type="textarea" value="" name="textarea">
    Notes:<input type="textarea" value="" name="textarea2">
    <input type="submit" id="sub" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<script>
    $('#sub').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $('#test').serialize();
        $.post('check.php', data, function (res) {
            console.log(res);
        })
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

in PHP

```
<?php

//if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']='submit') { // commented out submit buttons are not sent with ajax
    $data['value1'] = (float)$_POST['val1']; //values from input fields
    $data['value2'] = (float)$_POST['val2']; //values from input fields
    $data['value3'] = (float)$_POST['val3']; //values from input fields
    $data['value4'] = (float)$_POST['val4']; //values from input fields
    $data['value5'] = (float)$_POST['val5']; //values from input fields
    $data['value6'] = (float)$_POST['val6'];
    $data['textar'] = $_POST ['textarea'];//from textarea
    $data['textar2'] = $_POST ['textarea2']; //from textarea
//use echo to display the result of json_encode
    echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
//}
```

console log

[image: results]

Comment: just added to main window up above some code,does it changes something?

Comment: code is for sending data about paid payments to company. I simplified it,but only with var names, so it would be more clear